# Symfony Doctrine With RAW SQL won't pull up a field with date time

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a really odd issue. Using Symfony 2.0 and Doctrine with RAW sql from the command line (cronjob), it won't pull up a DB column that is a date time value.

It works fine on PHP MyAdmin so I know the sql isn't the issue. Is this a known Symfony issue?

```
$sql = 'SELECT 
    SessionDesign.sessionID, 
    SessionDesign.created, 
    fos_user.username, 
    fos_user.email 
FROM SessionDesign as SessionDesign
INNER JOIN `fos_user` AS fos_user ON SessionDesign.id = fos_user.fcid
WHERE fos_user.emailok = true';


$stmt = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
    ->getConnection()
    ->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$BaseCartData = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `getConnection()` returns a valid database connection and not `null`?

Comment: Ya I pulls up every other field but that one.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed you stated that in the question. What does the query return doctrine, `null`? Is there any log in the `app/logs/*.log` ?

Comment: The query return every fled i I search for expect for a date time feild. In fact it only pulls columns with the data time feild equal to null. Nothing useful in the log.

Comment: That's really odd. I've tried your code with slight changes to the query and I got all results containing the date time as a string. Are you sure you're not joining a column from `fos_user` which might be `null`, thus it's overriding your result?

Comment: Yes because it works 100% fine with RAW pdo queries. I think I'll leave it as straight PDO for now.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem here. It might be the old version of Symfony you're using. I tried it with the current 2.7 and doctrine 2.5 and it worked fine. Try posting a question in the github project of doctrine with a link to this question.

Comment: Is the `SessionDesign.created` properly mapped in the entity as `type=datetime`?

Comment: Yeah, anyway thanks guys. For all intensive purposes we decided just using PDO is fine. I think it's something to do with the server settings and doctrine.